# Unrealistic story in Rab Ne Bana Di Jodi

Tags: plot-explanation, rab-ne-bana-di-jodi

In the Hindi movie [Rab Ne Bana Di Jodi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rab_Ne_Bana_Di_Jodi),

> 'Taani' (Anushka Sharma) can not identify the 'Suri' (Sharukh Khan)
>   until 'Suri' reveals the truth himself, This is kind of unbelievable
>   and impractical as both 'Taani' & 'Suri' live in same house.

Do you think the fact that not being able to identify 'Suri' by 'Taani'
is giving any message to viewers or it is just a simple Bollywood story 
and we should not try to understand it deeply, because there are so many other things in the same movie which may seem unbelievable or unrealistic?

Comment: The producers think very less about these loop holes considering the viewers wont complain. But they should undertstand time has changed!

Comment: Yes, it's an extremely unrealistic film with a range of cliche and unbelievable scenarios.
I think spending time trying to deconstruct the storyline's motives and hidden meanings is a waste of our sanity. Films such as these rarely contain any groundbreaking revelations or deep understandings. It is a commercial film, with the intention of making lots of money and being popular for its beats.
@Manoj R rightly outlines the most obvious perceivable lesson from the movie, even if it was poorly conveyed visually.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you put it, its just a "simple Bollywood story". You should not read too much into it. Many of the film sequences (particularly the lavish song sets) also defy logic, but that's just what a typical Shahrukh Khan movie looks like. Personally I think that its just sad that script is the last thing in the minds of Hindi movie makers.

Comment: I understand your frustration with these movies. Although saying script is the last thing  in the minds of Hindi movie makers is generalizing to all movie makers. There are some real gems and classics that have been made by Hindi movie makers. To name a few Guru dutt, Raj Kumar Hirani, Anurag Kashyap. Movies lIke Taare Zameen Par etc. So please do not generalize Indian cinema. It has place for all kinds of movies and if you look at Hollywood or movies from any other countries there are bound to be all kinds of movies. Chick Flick, horror, etc all of them.

Answer (score 4):

I did agree with you. And hence my review baseline for movie is "when baseline is hollow, the building can't stand tall." 
Still if you force yourself, you can say that the lesson here is that true love does not see the face value, but the pure heart.

Comment: Wow to your love theory! :P :P